# Android Glide image caching: Starts new load even with preload

Tags: android, caching, android-glide

I am using Glide 3.8.0 in Android to prefetch the images:

```
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(imageUrl)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .preload();
```

With this I see the log that shows key with resolution [-2147483648x-2147483648]

```
V/Engine: Started new load in 1.75375ms, key: EngineKey{https://....com/uu/api/res/1.2/15USE5cHzsN75A26JngW_Q--/YXBwaWQ9eXRhY2h5b247Zmk9c3RyaW07aD0zNjA7dz02NDA7/http://....com/c026d208260f1b9d6880604661897d28+com.bumptech.glide.signature.EmptySignature@1341382+[-2147483648x-2147483648]+''+'ImageVideoBitmapDecoder.com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap'+''+'BitmapEncoder.com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap'+'GifBitmapWrapperDrawableTranscoder.com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.transcode'+''}
```

And when loading the actual image view, lookup is done with different size [1224x1020]:

```
V/Engine: Started new load in 0.45197899999999996ms, key: EngineKey{https://....com/uu/api/res/1.2/15USE5cHzsN75A26JngW_Q--/YXBwaWQ9eXRhY2h5b247Zmk9c3RyaW07aD0zNjA7dz02NDA7/http://....com/c026d208260f1b9d6880604661897d28+com.bumptech.glide.signature.EmptySignature@1341382+[1224x1020]+''+'ImageVideoBitmapDecoder.com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap'+''+'BitmapEncoder.com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap'+'GifBitmapWrapperDrawableTranscoder.com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.transcode'+''}
```

If I don't want to assume the size ahead of time, how can I cache it at all?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't cache images in memory unless they're the same size, so you'll need to know size ahead of time. It also needs to be the [same signature, transformation and any added options](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html#cache-keys). If any of these are different, your `EngineKey` hashCode will be different and it'll be a cache miss.

Note I'm assuming you're talking about memory caching as that's what `preload` is for and that's what the logs in `Engine` are talking about. You'll see `Started new load` in `Engine` for a memory cache miss and `Loaded resource from cache` for a memory cache hit.

If it's disk caching you're looking for, it's possible it's working as you intended. You need to enable the other logging to check this, so run `adb shell setprop log.tag.Glide VERBOSE` and look for either `Finished loading BitmapDrawable from DATA_DISK_CACHE` or `Finished loading BitmapDrawable from DATA_DISK_CACHE` or `Finished loading BitmapDrawable from RESOURCE_DISK_CACHE` in your LogCat.